# Magento 2 Advanced Search capital letter search not working for custom attribute

Tags: magento2

I have added some custom product attribute to advance search if I search for lower case letter then all work, but when I search using capital letter then it does not give any result.

the same thing is working for SKU search, but not working for another attribute.

Does anyone have any idea for the same?

Thanks